# parquet-cpp writer failed to generate readable parquet file if there are too many binary column

Tags: c++, parquet

I am trying to use the writer example in parquet-cpp to convert a CSV files with about 36 columns, they are all string columns, so set the column type as variable length byte array. I set the row group size to 1024. 
It can writer the schema out successfully, and I can read the meta/header using parquet-tools, but the data part always fail.
depend on the source data, I am getting following errors
`can not read class parquet.format.PageHeader: don't know what type: 14`
`Can not read value at 0 in block -1 in file`
can anyone share lights on how to use parquet-cpp correctly for this cases?

Comment: Can you post the code you have used? From the question it is hard to tell what went wrong. Be sure to set the UTF8 logical type on each String column, otherwise a lot of tools won't read the column.

Comment: Also check out the `parquet/arrow` api. Once you have constructed an Apache Arrow table, this will take care of the correct serialization to Parquet. This API is a bit more hig level and thus much more convenient to use.

Comment: hi xhonchy, thanks for the quick reply, my code is a direct modify of the reader-writer code in the example folders, I only use the byte array column writer in the example, remove all others, I also build it using ` g++ -o fo reader-writer.o  -lparquet -larrow`, the code works fine for less than 30 string columns, but yield above error when there are more than 30 columns. I also hard code the column size to be 128.

Comment: @xhochy, if I construct an Arrow table using the C++ Arrow API (e.g., like in [this tutorial](https://arrow.apache.org/docs/cpp/md_tutorials_row_wise_conversion.html)), how do I then write out the table to a Parquet file (gzipped)?

Comment: @rajcok Have a look at `src/parquet/arrow/writer.h` in parquet-cpp. There are some functions called `WriteTable`. These can then write out the file as you want to.